# Create still Image of a Video to display

Tags: android

I'm currently working of a file explorer for Google Glass and I would like to display a still image for every video I take. They should be bigger than the thumbnails already provided in Android, so I'm guessing I should create them myself from a video.
I'd be grateful if someone could push me into the right diection as to how to find a still image of a video file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way: Use [`ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). This will return an image at most 512 * 384 (for `MINI_KIND`).

You can also do it manually, with [`MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28%29). This should return a bitmap with the same dimensions as the video file.